# RestControllerAdvice is not working with custom annotations

Tags: spring, exception, spring-annotations, spring-restcontroller

I have two different controllers for two different versions of the API. I am trying to distinguish the exception handling too. Regarding this need I created custom annotations to distinguish the controllers. Here are the my code pieces:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApiV1 { }

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApiV2 { }

@ApiV1
@RequestMapping("/path")
@RestController
public class XYZControllerImpl implements com.xyz.XYZController { ... }  

@ApiV2
@RequestMapping("/v2/path")
@RestController
public class XYZControllerV2Impl implements com.xyz.v2.XYZController { ... }

@RestControllerAdvice(annotations = ApiV1.class)
public class ExceptionHandlerForV1 { ... }

@RestControllerAdvice(annotations = ApiV2.class)
public class ExceptionHandlerForV2 { ... }
```

The problem is here that when I run the tests for the version 1 implementation. Exceptions are not caught by the `ExceptionHandlerForV1`. The problem also mentioned [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16964), the solution didn't work for me but it seems I have all the necessary implementations.

If someone help me to solve this problem, I would be appreciate.

Note: We are using spring version `5.1.3.RELEASE`. Also, `ExceptionHandlerForV1` is working without annotations declaration.

Here is the sample failing test case:

```
@Test
public void testPostWithValidCredentialsWorks() throws Exception {

    mockServerWith200Response();

    // just POSTing without payload for simplicity
    mockMvc.perform(post(API_PATH)
            .with(createSampleCredentials()))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
}
```

Here is the result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<400> but was:<415>
Expected :400
Actual   :415
```

Comment: How do you test your controller? Can you please post the code of the tests?

Comment: Is it working at all without unit tests?

Comment: @caco3 I've updated the question. @Mykhailo Moskura, I am not sure right now, I have to do much stuff before I run the project, btw it was working without these custom annotations. I think that the problem is related to `HttpStatus 415` handling. I am still trying to investigate the root cause.